# Bootstrap datetimepicker current date and current time by default

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, eonasdan-datetimepicker

My Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker is configured as:

```
 $(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        minDate: moment(),
        keepInvalid: $('#start_date').val() ? true : false,
        sideBySide: true
        });
});
```

What I really need is to show the current date and time (like `moment()` function does) **only** if the value of the input form is empty (i.e. the appropriate field in the database is empty). And do not show the current date&time if the value is set.

In the current configuration it always shows me the current date & time ignoring the value from the database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to use `defaultDate` property instead of `minDate`:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: moment(),
        sideBySide: true
        });
});
```